# Creating a TurboModule in the app causes it to be undefined in react native's new architecture

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-turbomodule

I am trying to create a `TurboModule` for my app. I don't want to create it as a separate module as mentioned over [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules). I want it to be part of my app So I created a `RTNCalculator` folder inside that a `js` folder and created `NativeCalculator.ts` file. Then in the package.json of my application I added the following code

```
"codegenConfig": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "name": "NativeCalculator",
        "type": "modules",
        "jsSrcsDir": "./RTNCalculator/js"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My `NativeCalculator.ts` code

```
import type {TurboModule} from 'react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/RCTExport';
import {TurboModuleRegistry} from 'react-native';

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  add(a: number, b: number): Promise<number>;
  pickImage(): Promise<void>;
  someDummyMethod(): Promise<void>;
  addTwo(a: number, b: number): Promise<number>;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.get<Spec>('RTNCalculator') as Spec | null;
```

Then I ran `./gradlew generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema` and in the main `android` folder I created the following files

`CalculatorModule.kt` and `CalculatorPackage.kt`

```
class CalculatorPackage : TurboReactPackage() {
    override fun getModule(name: String, reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): NativeModule? {
        return if (name == CalculatorModule.NAME) {
            CalculatorModule(reactContext)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    override fun getReactModuleInfoProvider(): ReactModuleInfoProvider? {
        return ReactModuleInfoProvider {
            val moduleInfos: MutableMap<String, ReactModuleInfo> = HashMap()
            moduleInfos[CalculatorModule.NAME] = ReactModuleInfo(
                CalculatorModule.NAME,
                CalculatorModule.NAME,
                false,  // canOverrideExistingModule
                false,  // needsEagerInit
                true,  // hasConstants
                false,  // isCxxModule
                true // isTurboModule
            )
            moduleInfos
        }
    }
}


class CalculatorModule(context: ReactApplicationContext): NativeCalculatorSpec(context) {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return NAME
    }

    override fun add(a: Double, b: Double, promise: Promise?) {
        promise!!.resolve(a+b)
    }

    override fun pickImage(promise: Promise?) {

    }

    override fun someDummyMethod(promise: Promise?) {

    }

    override fun addTwo(a: Double, b: Double, promise: Promise?) {
        
    }

    companion object {
        const val NAME = "RTNCalculator"
    }
}
```

Then in MainApplication.java I added `packages.add(new CalculatorPackage());`

Then to use it in my `App.tsx`

```
import RTNCalculator from './RTNCalculator/js/NativeCalculator';
```

Now when I call the add method of `RTNCalculator` I get undefined. What am I missing?

I have enabled the new architecture for my app

Full source code https://github.com/BraveEvidence/TMTry

Comment: Are you using Hermes? Is it required for TurboModules?

Comment: Hermes is by default enabled in my project as my react native version is 0.71

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/turbomodule

Comment: I get 404 page...

Comment: @BraveEvidence Were you able to get this working. I am facing similar error

Comment: @RohitJindal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hI8o8pjcNg&list=PLQhQEGkwKZUrempLnmxjt7ZCZJu1W3p2i&index=5

Comment: @BraveEvidence In the video you shared it is still adding it as a dependency and not as a part of native code base. Did you also move away from creating it as a in app code part and moved it as a dependency

Comment: @RohitJindal yup I added it as dependency but you can follow this thread https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-new-architecture/discussions/142 if you want to add it as in app code